# Story with female scientist having sex with a self aware computer

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, sexuality

I read this story a long time ago. A female researcher is working with a budding AI and in the process she discovers sexual gratification. Interaction was via sensors and remote sex toy control escalating at the end to a full sensory suite.

I think the last line in the story goes something like: "I used to have a flute, now I have an orchestra,” delivered by the AI in regards to switching to a full sensory suit as opposed to controlling a single sex toy.

Comment: Well, this is going to be an interesting one to Google for ...

Comment: "*50 billion results found."*

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Yes... results are quite an eye opener with regards to available technology. At the time when the story was written, it was considered scifi. 90% of that story can pass for news today.

Comment: My +1 just for the interesting story...

Comment: Didn't find it, but did manage to find an article where researchers trained an AI by feeding it the works of Chuck Tingle.  Tapping out for the night, need to get drunk.

Comment: @Flatline - You should [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/198295/edit) additional details into the question

Comment: Was it the AI or the researcher who discovered sexual gratification?

Comment: Researcher was the one who found sexual gratification.

Comment: Possibly related?: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43726/scifi-short-story-about-a-woman-and-her-ai-boyfriend

Comment: I'm (vaguely) reminded of the "dueling instruments" bit from the movie *Electric Dreams*. It's not actually sexual, but the instrument references here simply remind me of it, and the AI in this case certainly has an interest in a relationship of some sort with the lady in question.

Answer (score 2):

(Credit to @AlanBailey for finding the *movie* version):

Info from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_Seed_(novel))

Was it the book *Demon Seed* by Dean Koontz?

There are two versions of the story; the 1973 version is about Susan, a “wealthy and beautiful woman” with a helpful home AI system. Proteus, a more intelligent computer, hijacks it and imprisons her, planning to impregnate her with a fetus and transfer his mind to it to become a human and controlling her through hypnosis and tentacles (creep).

The 1997 version depicts Susan as stronger, along with Proteus instead manipulating her through a mind-controlled servant. The child is an “insectoid human”, not a cyborg in the second version.

Comment: In this book, the woman is not a reseacher and in the version I read is more like a rape victim than a gratified participant..

Answer (score 1):

Betting you mean this: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075931/ Demon Seed. An underrated classic. The AI controls the house and becomes obsessed with Julie Christies character, and after holding her hostage, impregantes her.

Comment: Mmmh... OP was looking for a written work.

Comment: ‘Mmmh..’ It was originally a novel, written by Dean Koontz, prolific writer... didn’t you know?

Comment: I didn't. But in this case, I'd suggest answering with the novel, not the movie :)

Comment: In this book, the woman is not a reseacher and in the version I read is more like a rape victim than a gratified participant.